# Meteor Upsert Restricted Collection 403 Error

Tags: meteor

I'm discovering Meteor and something goes wrong with a collection upsert I'm trying to run. I'm getting the following error:

```
errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Access denied. Upserts not allowed in a restricted collection."…}
```

I don't really understand what happens, here is the client code:

```
pages = Pages.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
PageId = (pages) ? pages._id : null;  // The PageId should be null in my situation
Pages.upsert(PageId, {$set: {"pages.facebook.url": "url"}}, {multi: false}, function(err, docs) {
    // callback code
});
```

And the permissions: (server side)

```
Pages = new Meteor.Collection('pages');

Pages.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return userId !== null;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc) {
        return userId == doc.userId;
    },
    remove: function(userId, doc) {
        return userId == doc.userId;
    }
});
```

Comment: The error happens on the server-side?

Comment: I'm running the code on the client side. Only permissions above are on the server side.

Comment: Right. Well, that was quite an important difference :)

Comment: Don't you need to add an `insert` function to your `Pages.allow` to guarantee that the `upsert` will work?

Comment: Yes that's what I did as Hubert suggested. But I get the same error. In fact, what I'm trying to do is a create or update. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update from the client, you cannot pass an object as a selector, just the single `_id` of the object you're updating. So instead of

```
Pages.upsert({_id: PageId}, ...);
```

simply write

```
Pages.upsert(PageId, ...);
```

---

**Edit:** also, in your allow block you don't grant any permission for creating new objects, so the operation will fail due to restricted access. Add `insert` param to your allow method.

Comment: thx, I made this change but I get the same result. It's probably because PageId is null in my situation?

Comment: I've found a second problem and updated the answer. Please check again :)

Comment: Thx, I made this change too and return always true to insert (is it a good way to do that?) but I get the same error.

Comment: Usually I'd check whether userId is not null so that unlogged users cannot insert a random doc. But that may depend on the case.

Comment: I don't know what else might be causing this error. In your question you still call `upsert` with `{_id: ...}` as a param, but I assume you've changed that in code? Try replacing the upsert with insert / update pair so that insert is called in the mentioned case. Does the error persist then?

Comment: That's what I did, a simple insert. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen this, I too faced issue on simple update as well with some fields in collection definition having `defaultValue`.

I ended up to a [link](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/issues/146), which says that there is a simple hack to this to resolve the issue. Below is the code,

```
const defaultValue = value => function autoValue() {
  if (!this.isUpdate && !this.isUpsert && !this.isSet) {
    return value;
  }
};  

// Schema field definition
fieldName: {
  type: Number,
  autoValue: defaultValue(10),
}
```

So, from above code it is clear that you have to replace `defaultValue : YOUR_VALUE` with `autoValue: defaultValue(YOUR_VALUE)`