# meteor.js - upsert does not throw a console error, but doesn't insert data

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I'm trying to update or insert data with `upsert`, but it doesn't work.

Neither update nor insert doesn't work...
but I don't see any errors both in terminal and console.

Does anybody see something wrong in my code?

This is inside of function where I insert or update data, also I use SimpleSchema for the Measures collection.

```
  questions.forEach(question => {
     Measures.upsert(question._id, {
       $set: {
         title: question.text,
         type:
           question.type === QuestionType.SHORT_ANSWER
             ? MeasureType.TEXT
             : MeasureType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
         typeOptions: {frequency},
         shortCodeOptions: {},
         entity: System.getCurrentEntity(),
       },
     });
   });
```

Reference : [Meteor Upsert Restricted Collection 403 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493094/meteor-upsert-restricted-collection-403-error)

[Mongodb update and insert data at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015705/mongodb-update-and-insert-data-at-the-same-time-upsert-react-js-meteor-js)

meteor version :2.5.0

**ADDED**
Update part is solved.
The selector which in this case is `{_id: question._id}` was not actually matched.

```
        questions.forEach(question => {
          const questionId = Measures.findOne({questionId: question._id}); // added
          Measures.upsert(
            {_id: questionId?._id},
            {
              $set: {
                title: question.text,
                type:
                  question.type === QuestionType.SHORT_ANSWER
                    ? MeasureType.TEXT
                    : MeasureType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
                typeOptions: {frequency},
                shortCodeOptions: {},
                entity: System.getCurrentEntity(),
              },
            },
          );
        });
```

But I still won't be able to insert a new data, because if the date doesn't exist, there is no `questionId` .

I added question mark to `{_id: questionId?._id}` just to hide a error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') meteor` but this is not solving the issue.

How can I insert a new data?

Comment: Try to remove the SimpleSchema, and see what happen. Another suggestion, change `question._id` to `{_id: question._id}`

Comment: @RicardoAragão I actually had ```{_id: question._id}``` first but I got an error saying ```Access denied. Upserts not allowed in a restricted collection.``` So I switched to ```question._id``` .  But I tried ```{_id: question._id}``` again, not seeing the error anymore but still can't upsert data

Comment: It is right, because to upsert you can't use ID. You need to use another field.

Comment: You can use the title in this case, because no make sense has questions with same title, right?

Comment: @RicardoAragão I appreciate your answer! but filtering by title actually didn't work out... I posted [a updating version in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049479/meteor-how-to-use-upsert-exception-while-simulating-the-effect-of-invoking-t), I will be grateful if you could take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing things here and I am not sure if `question` is a document from the `Measures` collection or from a different collection.

### Option A - `question` is a document from the `Measures` collection

If so, you need to get rid of `questionId` and use `_id`

```js
        questions.forEach(question => {
          Measures.upsert(
            { _id: question._id },
            {
              $set: {
                title: question.text,
                type:
                  question.type === QuestionType.SHORT_ANSWER
                    ? MeasureType.TEXT
                    : MeasureType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
                typeOptions: {frequency},
                shortCodeOptions: {},
                entity: System.getCurrentEntity(),
              },
            },
          );
        });
```

### Option B - `question` is a document from a different Collection

Then you need to explicitly set `questionId` as field on $set:

```js
        questions.forEach(question => {
          Measures.upsert(
            { questionId: question._id }},
            {
              $set: {
                title: question.text,
                questionId: question._id, // required to associate measures with questions
                type:
                  question.type === QuestionType.SHORT_ANSWER
                    ? MeasureType.TEXT
                    : MeasureType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
                typeOptions: {frequency},
                shortCodeOptions: {},
                entity: System.getCurrentEntity(),
              },
            },
          );
        });
```

Tip: Context is important, which is why you should always clarify relations between documents and collections when asking questions.

Comment: I know nothing about mongodb so I mixed up collection and document, but now I'm clear! Also Thank you for your help!